# Linux disable app launcher and edit right click menu

Tags: linux, desktop-customization

I need a Linux Desktop Environment where I can disable the application launcher menu and also remove everything from the right-click menu except the option to open a Terminal. Which desktop environment would be most suitable for this goal? I would do the GUI customization as the root user, doing those changes for other user accounts in the system.

Comment: which Desktop Environment features do you need?  TWM can be configured and locked down but it is just a window manager. preventing the user from creating `~/.twmrc` could be tricky

Comment: Did you try firing up a pure vanilla `Openbox` session, yet? Then remove anything from the already sparse right click menu using the config files. Won't stop users from defining their own config files, though. Side question: if you want to allow terminals only, why offer a GUI in the first place?

Comment: I only need the ability to Launch 2 applications from the desktop with their icons and disable everything else, except the ability to open a terminal from the right-click context menu.